# Brackets appear when you insert a Label in the Array (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I have code to store a number in an array from a **Label**.

```
@IBAction func MSSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    MSarrayResults.removeAll()
    if let MSText = displayResultLabel.text {
        let result = "\(MSText)"
        MSarrayResults.append(result as AnyObject)
        print ("\(MSText)")
    }
}
```

**Button to display the array on the screen (displayResultLabel)**

```
@IBAction func MRRead(_ sender: UIButton) {
    displayResultLabel.text = "\(MSarrayResults)"
}
```

But when I insert the array into the Label brackets appear (**Look Photo**).

[image]

Comment: Your are dealing with an array, and the (string) description used by String Interpolation (`"\()"`) of an array is `"[value1, value2]"`. What do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing:

```
displayResultLabel.text = "\(MSarrayResults)"
```

is setting the text to the "default string representation" of an array. That typically looks like this (if you have 5 numbers in the array):

```
[5, 7, 85, 13, 9]
```

or, as you have seen:

```
[85]
```

if you have only one number in the array.

Essentially, it is a "human readable" representation.

If you want to set the text to the first element in your array, you can use:

```
displayResultLabel.text = "\(MSarrayResults.first)"
```

or:

```
displayResultLabel.text = "\(MSarrayResults[0])"
```

However, since your `MSSave()` function is *removing* all elements from `MSArrayResults` before it appends the new string, it doesn't make any sense to use an array when you could simply use a String variable.